# ASP.NET MVC2 e-mail templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, email, templates

With Web Forms I used to generate e-mails by loading ascx control and capturing it's output.

What is the clean solution to use ASP.NET MVC 2 with default WebForms View engine to generate e-mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I'm using:

http://msug.vn.ua/blogs/bobasoft/archive/2010/01/07/render-partialview-to-string-asp-net-mvc.aspx